# ext4 enable hashes for directory entries

Tags: linux, filesystems, storage, ext4

According to [kernel.org](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Hash_Tree_Directories) there is the possibility to store dentries in trees instead of lists but you need to enable this flag (EXT4_INDEX_FL) in the inode structure. I this enabled by default or I have to format my partition with some flags?

I need to store lots of small files (same old problem) of about 130k each and I understood that this will help to speed up lookup and also that it is recommended to store those files in a 2 level directories hierarchy. Is there something else I need to consider so that this doesn't blow up if want to store something close to 60.000.000 of this kind of files ? (maybe some other values for block size, number of blocks in a group)

Comment: I'm wondering some times how those decisions take place. Do you guys meet in some bar or at a beer over a skype call? Do I need to paste code in order to not make it generic? I could invent some pseudo code and post the question in such a way that the answer whould be the solution to that pseudocode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This option is referred to by the e2fsprogs suite as `dir_index`.  It's enabled by default, and you can verify that it's enabled on a file system by running `tune2fs -l DEVICE` as root.

It is indeed recommended that you shard your files manually so that you don't have a huge number of files in the same directory.  While using B-trees makes the operation O(log n) instead of O(n), for large numbers of files, the operation can still be expensive.

If you know you're going to be creating a large number of files, you can set the inode ratio to 4096 with the `-i` option; this will create a larger number of inodes so that you can hold more files.  You can also see common settings for a large number of situations in `/etc/mke2fs.conf`.